# Renaming raw reads with Snakemake rules

Tags: python, snakemake

I want to generalise one of my pipelines and facilitate downstream analysis. I use this function to consistently rename the raw fastq files before passing them to the pipeline.

```
## Functions: 

samples = pd.read_csv(parameters["reference"]["samples_csv"], dtype="str")
population = samples['pop'].drop_duplicates().tolist()
individual = samples["ind"].drop_duplicates().tolist()

### Get the samples names
def get_sequences(wildcards):
    pop = wildcards.population
    ind = wildcards.individual
    R1, R2 = (samples[(samples["pop"] == pop) & (samples["ind"] == ind)][["R1", "R2"]].values.tolist()[0])
    return R1, R2
```

But at the moment, I keep getting this error:

```
Error:
  IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
Wildcards:
  population=<function <lambda> at 0x155547fda820>
  individual=<function <lambda> at 0x155547fda8b0>
```

The error is that get_sequences tries to find all possible combinations of population and individual, but the individuals' names differ for each population. Since the output of get_sequences is being used in this rule:

```
rule symlinks:
    input:
        get_sequences
    output:
        R1 = "data/raw/{population}.{individual}_1.fq.gz",
        R2 = "data/raw/{population}.{individual}_2.fq.gz",
    log:
        R1 = "logs/make_symlinks/{population}.{individual}_1.log",
        R2 = "logs/make_symlinks/{population}.{individual}_2.log",
    shell:
        """
        ln --symbolic $(readlink --canonicalize {input[0]}) {output.R1} > {log.R1} 2>&1
        ln --symbolic $(readlink --canonicalize {input[1]}) {output.R2} > {log.R2} 2>&1
        """
```

I want to keep get_sequence or something similar working. I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip to solve this issue.
This is my minimum example.

`sample.csv`

```
pop     ind
population1     individual1
population1     individual2
population2     individual3
population2     individual5
population2     individual6
```

```
import pandas as pd

samples = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", sep="\t")

POPULATION = samples['pop']
INDIVIDUAL = samples['ind']

rule all:
    input:
        expand(["data/raw/{population}.{individual}_1.fq.gz", "data/raw/{population}.{individual}_2.fq.gz"], zip, population = POPULATION, individual = INDIVIDUAL),


rule test:
    output:
        touch("data/raw/{population}.{individual}_1.fq.gz"),
        touch("data/raw/{population}.{individual}_2.fq.gz"),
```

Answer (score 1):

We usually make our workflows generalizable by providing the input file names in some `.tsv` (tab-separated) file that gives an overview of `samples` or `units` (for sequencing, where you might for example have multiple sequencing lanes per sample in separate input files). Here's a workflow with a rather minimal setup for this. Have a look at:

- [The `units.tsv` file for the CI tests.](https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/dna-seq-short-read-circle-map/blob/6f450f0f2da0afcc0edb17870bfcc57ab03bd717/.test/config/units.tsv?plain=1#L2)
- [The code that reads in the `units.tsv` file.](https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/dna-seq-short-read-circle-map/blob/6f450f0f2da0afcc0edb17870bfcc57ab03bd717/workflow/rules/common.smk#L55-L60)
- [The input function that uses the resulting `units` pandas table for lookup with the respective wildcards.](https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/dna-seq-short-read-circle-map/blob/6f450f0f2da0afcc0edb17870bfcc57ab03bd717/workflow/rules/common.smk#L96-L104)
- [The rule that uses the files as input.](https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/dna-seq-short-read-circle-map/blob/6f450f0f2da0afcc0edb17870bfcc57ab03bd717/workflow/rules/trimming.smk#L1-L15)

This might seem like a lot of loose ends at first, but it leads to a very easily configurable setup. For the example workflow mentioned here, check out the [snakemake workflow catalog usage instructions (in particular, step 3)](https://snakemake.github.io/snakemake-workflow-catalog/?usage=snakemake-workflows/dna-seq-short-read-circle-map).

Also, there is [further suggestions for more standardized workflow setups in the snakemake docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/deployment.html).